# prevent users to click radio button after attempts are completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have one application..in that i display all questions and gave options as radio buttons..

so what i want to do is i need to restrict the user to select radio button only two attempts..for third attempt i don't want to allow the user to click radio button.and need to give alert like your attempts are completed..

And when user select one radio button then after select another radio button i want to calculate time difference between two attempts..

please help me how to do this..i have no idea how to do this..

thank you

Comment: Are you using javascript or pure php forms ?

Comment: paste a code block what you have tried earlier

Comment: Please edit your question with your code .

Comment: Interesting specification. But we do not produce code from specification here

Comment: i am using javascript and php..i didn't try any code yet?because i have no idea on how to do this..please help me how to do this..

Comment: attach code of radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('input[name="radio"]').click(function(){
        if(count < 2)
      {
        count++;
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Limit reached');
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/2/)

Comment: but how can i calculate time difference between two attempts

Comment: You can calculate it in js

Comment: ya i know..can you please explain in code..how we will do that..i tried that one from the past one week..but it's not coming..please help me...

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/4/ here you get three timestamps on which click is done. Use it as you want

Comment: can i use id="radio" instead of name="radio"  because in my radio buttons names are like this <input type="radio" value="3" name="question_<?php echo $key ?>"><?= $value->answer3; ?><br>

Comment: No you cannot use id, as id refers to single instance. Use class instead

Comment: you mean class="radio" right? but when i use like this it's not working

Comment: No $('.clasName'); like this

Comment: Here I am giving you direction only, you have to implement your own logic